# "Beautifying" a URL in Yii

Tags: url-rewriting, yii

I want to convert a URL which is of the format

> path/to/my/app/Controller_action/id/2

to

> path/to/my/app/Controller_action/id/User_corresponding_to_id_2

I have already seen [this](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/topics.url#using-custom-url-rule-classes) tutorial from Yii, but it isnt helping me with anything. Can anyone help me with this?

**EDIT**: I would also like to know if this thing is even possible in the POST scenario, ie I will only have path/to/my/app/Controller_action in the URL.

Comment: Is there a reason you need to use Yii to do the rewriting? This would be a lot simpler with a .htaccess rewrite rule. http://roshanbh.com.np/2008/03/url-rewriting-examples-htaccess.html

Comment: The thing is that its all dynamic. If I had to convert path/user="someName" to path/someName, I would have gladly written it in the .htaccess file.

Comment: Regarding your edit: Really don't do things like that. The use of POST is only accepted when data is going to change in your database. It will also present visitors with a "are you sure you want to post the form again" popup all the time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a getUrl method in your User model

```
public function getUrl()
{
    return Yii::app()->createUrl('controller/action', array(
    'id'=>$this->id,
    'username'=>$this->username,
    ));
}
```

Add the following rule `urlManager` component in `config/main.php`

```
'controller/action/<username:.*?>/<id: \d+>'=>'controller/action'
```

**And use the models `url` virtual attribute everywhere**

Comment: Hey, this thing works, but I need a few more clarifications. One thing is, now i need to add username as a parameter to my action function!! And also, can you tell me how I can create a similar thing when I **POST** a page and dont GET it.

Comment: I didn't get what you meant by POST a page. Please clarify, If possible explain with an example

Comment: I mean Form actions - GET and POST. I think this URL rewriting works only for GET (ie passing parameters in the url). Am I wrong?

Answer (score 1):

dInGd0nG is on the correct track, but if I understand correctly you wish to do actions based on the actual username instead of the ID as well right?

It's not that hard in Yii. I'm assuming here for simplicity the controller is user and the action is view.

Your User controller:

```
public function actionView($id)
{
    if (is_numeric($id))
       $oUser = User::model()->findByPk($id);
    else
       // Luckily Yii does parameter binding, wouldn't be such a good idea otherwise :)
       $oUser = User::model()->findByAttributes(array('username' => $id));

    ...
}
```

Your urlManager config:

```
'user/view/<id: \w+>' => 'user/view',
```

Or more generally:

```
'user/<action: \w+>/<id: \w+> => 'user/<action>',
```

To generate a user url in a view:

```
 $this->createUrl('user/view', array('id' => $oUser->username));
```