# Yii CUrlManager rules - how to add custom text from model to url

Tags: php, url-rewriting, seo, yii

I have urls like this

> example.com/model/id
>
> example.com/image/123 (default rules)

I would rewrite it to:

> example.com/category/123-this_is_encoded_title.html

My image model have following attributes:

- id
- title
- category
  ...

I need to add category from model to url.
How can i add category name dynamic to the url?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it seems that you already using some default CUrlManager rules.

Add below rule at top of your rule list. (I am assuming your controller id is **image**)

```
'<category:\w+>/<id:\d+>-<title:\w+>.html'=>'image/view',
```

besides this, you have to change url creation in all places.  You have to pass **title** and **category** values as the url params.

ex:

```
//Cleanup the title and category
$model->title = preg_replace("/[^\w+]/", '_', $model->title);
$model->category = preg_replace("/[^\w+]/", '_', $model->category);

//ex 1:
$this->redirect(array('view',
         'id'=>$model->id, 
         'title'=>$model->title, 
         'category' => $model->category
));

//ex 2:
echo CHtml::link('Title', array('view',
         'id'=>$data->id,
         'title' => $data->title, 
         'category' => $data->category
 ));

//ex 3:
$this->createUrl('image/view', array(
         'id'=>$image->id, 
         'title'=>$image->title, 
         'category' => $image->category
));
```

This answer explains what you need to do.

Please follow the @dInGd0nG suggestion for code re-factoring.

Comment: wont work. The value of `category` is dynamic. Its not a fixed value i think

Comment: in that case, we can make it dynamic and pass it in url creation. I'll modify my answer then.

Comment: this was tested with my Member model, perfectly worked. `'<last_name:\w+>/<id:\d+>-<first_name:\w+>.html'=>'member/view',`

Comment: there is a better way. We wont need to specify all these params everywhere, Just add a `getUrl()` in model and use $model->url . For more info check http://stackoverflow.com/a/10595343/1362777